# Web API sent data without value

Tags: php, json, postman

I created the following scripts to send data to server, but when I use postman to send data in json format it sent blanks data, the following are my scripts

```
 <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");


//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","wamesh","wames9est","wam90est")
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));




// recieved from app
$mtitle = $_POST['mytitle'];
$mdate = $_POST['mydate'];
$mnews = $_POST['mynews'];


echo "Response: ".$mtitle." ";


$sql_query = "INSERT INTO news (title,news,time) VALUES ('$mtitle','$mnews','$mdate')";


if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query)) {
    echo "We just posted a news response!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql_query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

and this is a sample of data I try to  send

```
{
    "mytitle": "COVID 19 Updates",
    "mynews": "COVID 19 - Breaking News",
    "mydate": "19 may 2020"
}
```

in postman it shows success but in database I just found row added but no values inside.

Comment: print the content of `$_POST` to clarify what data is received by the server

Comment: The code works on my end. Be sure to close:  mysqli_close($connection);    And make sure your form specified  method="post"

Comment: Setting this response header: `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");` makes no sense because your script is outputting plain text or HTML, not JSON

Comment: This might help you with receiving the data from postman: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: Also: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli

Answer (score -1):

Check the `$_POST` if it contain any data and use prepared statemnt when dealing with DB. Yours can be SQL Injection